# React native thunk "Possible unhandled promise" error despite providing onReject callback?

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-thunk

Using react native, getting a `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection` error when using a firebase.Promise (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise) in a redux action thunk (https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#actions-js-asynchronous), eg.

```
....
console.log(`Reuthenticating for user ${user.displayName}, ${user.email}`)
credentials = 'intentionally bad credential type'
user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credentials)
.then(
    (res) => {console.log(`Reauth complete: ${res}`)},
    (error) => {console.log(`Something bad happend ${error}`)})
....
```

(authenticating as recommended here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user) via `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential)) produces the message

> ```
> [18:45:12] Reuthenticating for user me, me@gmail.com
> [18:45:14] Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> [18:45:14] [Error: reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential failed: First argument "credential" must be a valid credential.]
> ```

without printing the console.log() message (which indicates to me that this is not just a warning, but an actual error). Even though I am providing an `onReject` callback to `.then()` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.Promise#then).

Some other SO posts suggest appending a `.catch()` to the promise (rather then providing an on onReject fallback callback in the promise's .then() like I do), but since am using a thunk action here, this is not recommended (see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6895#issuecomment-281405036). Anyone know what could be happening here or some steps to debug further?

Comment: `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` is a function you wrote (like wrapper) or is it a build in API in firebase?. If possible can you show the code for `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential`?

Comment: @RaviRaj It's a firestore web API function (the older function `reauthenticateWithCredential` is now depreciated (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#reauthenticateWithCredential)). Added a link to the docs in the question.